# Retrieve idToken and refreshToken in Firebase-admin Python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I need to retrieve idToken and refreshToken of a user(`firebase_admin._user_mgt.UserRecord object`). This is the function I use to create a new user with flask.

```
@app.route('/user/SignUp')
def user_signup():
    """ Sign up new users """

    email = request.args.get('email')
    password = request.args.get('password')

    try:
        new_user = auth.create_user(
            email=email,
            email_verified=False,
            password=password,
            disabled=False)
        print ("- - - new user created - - - ")


    except Exception as e:
        print ("- - - create_user error : {} - - - ".format(str(e)))
        return jsonify(
            error=str(e),
            status="FAILED"
        )
```

If we use bellow web API endpoint it responses with both keys `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser`

docs :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-create-email-password

Is there a way to achieve this without using the web API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't retrieve ID token and refresh token using Admin SDK `create_user` API. You have to use the client SDKs to do so.

Comment: thanks for answering. Can you explain the answer little bit?

Comment: Admin SDK user management APIs never issue ID tokens, you have to use client SDKs to do so. For example to get the ID token of an email/password user, you have to call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` from client SDK to get the ID token and not the admin sdk API `create_user`, etc.

Comment: Feel free to check the references. [`create_user`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#create_user) returns a [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserRecord) which does not provide any tokens. Unlike the firebase client side user which has a `getIdToken()` method, none is available there.

Comment: You have mentioned that I have to call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. So where is it available?

Comment: Here is the web client API reference link for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve ID Token, but using the Admin API you can create one custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(uid)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens